# Using for loops to guess words for hangman

Tags: python, python-3.x

```python
def get_guess(past_guesses):      
    """
    Checks if past_guesses is 1 letter, a letter or has been used before, and 
    prompts user to try again

    Args:past_guesses:a st, one letter long
    Returns: 'You need to enter one alphabetic character which you haven\'t 
    already guessed. Try again'

    Example:
    >>> get_guess([a, a])
    'You need to enter one alphabetic character which you haven\'t 
    already guessed. Try again'
    >>> get_guess([A, a])
    'You need to enter one alphabetic character which you haven\'t 
    already guessed. Try again'
    >>> get_guess([1])
    'You need to enter one alphabetic character which you haven\'t 
    already guessed. Try again'
    """
    counter = 0
    p = [x.lower() for x in past_guesses]
    for i in past_guesses:
        if i in past_guesses:
            counter += 1
        if counter > 2:
            result = "'You need to enter one alphabetic character which you\
            haven't already guessed. Try again'"
        elif :
            result = p, 'is in the word'
        return result
```

Hi. I am having trouble figuring out how to write a code that will help us write out a string from a list (past_guessed) of letters that have already been guessed for the hangman word.

Comment: `for i in past_guesses: if i in past_guesses: ...` `i` will always be in `past_guesses`....

Comment: Anyway, your question is not really clear. Please provide a some example input with desired output. And please provide a [mcve], the code you have here would throw a NameError

Comment: Do you really expect people to try to read that code in a comment? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52940145/edit) with the relevant details.

Comment: And again, provide a [mcve], emphasis on the *minimal*. We don't need to mess with user inputs. Give us example input and output of what you are trying to accomplish specifically.

Comment: Your example is a little confusing. `for i in past_guesses` means that `i` is always in past_guesses inside the loop, making your `if i in past_guesses` always true by definition.

Comment: Your `elif` has no condition.

Comment: Your examples contain the undefined variables `a` and `A`. Maybe you meant to make those strings?